# I dont see the "incomming email setting" in my list settings

Tags: 2010, email, incoming-email

I found alot of tutorials how to enable incomming email settings for lists or libraries. I have installed smtp in my iis 6.0. The smtp is working because did try to send some test mails with an smtp test tool.

I have enabled the incomming email option in the central admin. Please see attachment for the settings I selected.

When I create a new list and go to list settings, I dont see the option "incomming email setting". What do I missing?!

[Incomming mail settings in CA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43shB.jpg)

Comment: Maybe I found the solution. Create a library. Then go to the settings, and there you will see this option. Is this option only visible in a library? I would like to create a content type and and use it in a new list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incoming email is only available in select lists and libraries.

- Document, picture, or form library
- Announcements list
- Calendar list
- Discussion board
- Blog

[Reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/enable-and-configure-e-mail-support-for-a-list-or-library-HA010082307.aspx)

So you'd need to use one of these lists or libraries as your base, remove the default content type and add your own.